# Can my profile contain advertisement?

Tags: discussion

Doing advertisement in questions or answers is spamming, but can I include advertisement in the about box or is that also forbidden?

Actually I am doing this in  my about, so I wanted to be sure. ;)

Comment: Can you link to a pyramid scheme in your profile? Seems like the answer is yes. I doubt anybody will fall for it anyways...

Comment: The one thing pyramid schemes have in common is they all say they aren't a pyramid scheme.

Comment: Well, it does say the most important rule for earning points is to make your friends and family join, which feels like a ponzi scheme in disguise. But you're right that there's no investment from the user so it's not exactly harmful. So it's half pyramid scheme, half messenger? Still better than whatsapp I guess ;)

Comment: Saying what you do seems reasonable, but yours is just a blatant ad nobody is likely to read.

Comment: On a related note - is it possible to downvote a profile?

Comment: @patricksweeney So if I wanted to start a pyramid scheme but wanted to hide the fact that it's a pyramid scheme, I should say up front that it's a pyramid scheme because according to your theory that would prove that it isn't a pyramid scheme?  :) :)

Comment: @ajb: Touché. The sad thing is that blatant ads like those do somehow work or else people wouldn't bother - but ELSEWHERE, certainly not here on SO. Don't know about anyone else, but the moment I see something like that, it's a sort of indicator for me.

Comment: Can i advertise the advertisement on my profile in meta..? ;)

Comment: @TJ Sure - its a meta advertisement (surely that belongs on meta?)

Comment: @BobJarvis Never in my life have I so wanted to double upvote a comment.

Comment: Pretty much all Freemium games are pyramid schemes, except that you don't really get any value back (ie, you get more turns/etc. if you get your friends to join); which makes me wonder if they're gateway drugs to pyramid schemes?

Comment: You can include offensive content in your bio...did you know that? (I once tried to flag a user saying that their bio was offensive, but it was declined by a moderator who said that the bio is allowed to contain such content as it is "not as in front as posts or comments are".)

Comment: @patricksweeney [Relevant](http://youtu.be/a231RLKyfPw?t=53s)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can put (virtually) anything you want in your about me section on your profile. Links are "no followed" so you won't get any Google ranking improvements though.

Things you can't put in your profile include (but are not limited to):

- pornographic images
- hate speech and other racist, sexist etc. language and images

Comment: Is no-follow universal in profiles now?  IIRC the restriction was removed from links in high rep users profiles when the site was new.

Comment: @DanNeely I think high-rep users are exempted from a nofollow on their "website" field (mine is, anyway, and some lower-rep users' had a nofollow), but links in the freeform profile text are always nofollowed.

Comment: Not really that second point. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @apsillers Just being really pedantic, but links in the freeform text that are *exactly the same* (`String.equal`) as the website link won't get nofollowed if the website link doesn't.